# The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I’m creating a settings command but it produces a lot of errors, I can’t figure out how to fix them for a long time, I tried some methods but they didn’t work and should I do it all in the collector or should I try to do it at an event without a collector, but then I don’t know how to keep track for the one who executed the command

Command:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');
const guild = require('../../database/GuildSchema');
const emoji = require('../../json/emoji.json');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('settings')
        .setDescription('Показывает текущие настройки сервера и управление ими.'),
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const selectMenu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('settings')
            .setPlaceholder('Выберите подходящую настройку')
            .addOptions(
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Цвета')
                    .setEmoji('')
                    .setDescription('Изменить цвет эмбедов')
                    .setValue('color'),
            );

        const deleteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('delete-message')
            .setLabel('Закрыть')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(selectMenu);

        const buttons = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(deleteButton);

        const startEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Ожидается выбор конфигурации")
            .setDescription(`> Выберите нужную вам конфигурацию через меню выбора ниже\n`)
            .addFields({
                name: "Текущая конфигурация:",
                value: `Цвет сообщений: \`${(await client.getColor(interaction.guildId)).toString(16)}\``
            })
            .setColor(await client.getColor(interaction.guildId));

        if (interaction.user.id === interaction.member.user.id) {
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [startEmbed], components: [row, buttons]});
        } else {
            await interaction.reply("Извините, только пользователь, вызвавший команду, может использовать эту команду.");
        }
    }
};
```

InteractionCreate:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const guild = require('../../database/GuildSchema');
const MatrixBotListener = require("../../struct/MatrixBotListener");

class InteractionCreate extends MatrixBotListener {
    constructor() {
        super('InteractionCreateEvent', { event: 'interactionCreate' });
    }
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const guildId = interaction.guildId;

        const guildConfig = await guild.findOne({id: guildId});

        const selectMenu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('settings')
            .setPlaceholder('Выберите подходящую настройку')
            .addOptions(
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Цвета сообщений')
                    .setEmoji('')
                    .setDescription('Изменить цвет сообщений бота')
                    .setValue('color'),
            );

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(selectMenu);

        const deleteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('delete-message')
            .setLabel('Закрыть')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

        const buttons = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents([
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('back')
                    .setLabel('Назад')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)])
            .addComponents([
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('change-color')
                    .setLabel('Изменить цвет')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)])
            .addComponents([
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('reset-color')
                    .setLabel('Сбросить')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                    .setDisabled(!guildConfig?.embed_color)])

        const delete_Button = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(deleteButton);

        let colorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Настройка цвета сообщений бота')
            .setDescription('> Воспользуйтесь кнопками ниже для взаимодействия с меню.\n> Изменение цвета сообщений подразумевает изменение цвета, который отображается слева во всех эмбед сообщениях.\n\n' +
                'Вы также можете воспользоваться полезной утилитой [HEX](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/) для подбора цвета!\n\n' +
                'Чтобы изменить цвет, нажмите кнопку "Изменить цвет", затем введите HEX-код цвета в соответствующее поле в модальном окне и подтвердите его.\n\n' +
                '> Примечание: цвет должен быть в формате HEX (например, #FF0000 для красного цвета), иначе изменение не будет выполнено.')

            .addFields({
                name: "Текущий цвет сообщений:",
                value: `\`#${(await client.getColor(interaction.guildId)).toString(16)}\``
            })
            .setColor(await client.getColor(interaction.guildId));

        const filter = (i) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter, time: 10000 });

        let startEmbed = colorEmbed;

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            try {
                if (i.isStringSelectMenu()) {
                    if (i.values[0] === 'color') {
                        await i.update({embeds: [colorEmbed], components: [buttons]});
                    }
                }

                if (i.customId === 'delete-message') {
                    await i.message.delete();
                    collector.stop("Сообщение удалено");
                    return;
                }

                if (i.customId === 'back') {
                    const startEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle("Ожидается выбор конфигурации")
                        .setDescription(`> Выберите нужную вам конфигурацию через меню выбора ниже\n`)
                        .addFields({
                            name: "Текущая конфигурация:",
                            value: `Цвет сообщений: ${guildConfig?.embed_color}`
                        })
                        .setColor(guildConfig?.embed_color || '#4860fa');

                    await i.editReply({content: "", embeds: [startEmbed], components: [row, delete_Button]});
                }

                if (i.customId === 'reset-color') {
                    await guild.findOneAndDelete({id: guildId});
                    colorEmbed.data.fields[0].value = `\`стандартный (#4860fa)\``;
                    colorEmbed.data.color = await client.getColor(interaction.guildId);
                    buttons.components[2].setDisabled(true);
                    await i.update({content: "", embeds: [colorEmbed], components: [buttons]});
                }

                if (i.customId === 'change-color') {
                    const id = Math.random().toString(16);

                    i.showModal(
                        new ModalBuilder()
                            .setCustomId(id)
                            .setTitle("Напишите hex код цвета")
                            .addComponents(new ActionRowBuilder()
                                .addComponents(
                                    new TextInputBuilder()
                                        .setCustomId("color-input")
                                        .setLabel("HEX")
                                        .setStyle(1)
                                        .setMinLength(7)
                                        .setMaxLength(7)
                                        .setPlaceholder("#fffff")
                                        .setRequired(true)
                                )
                            )).catch(console.error);
                    i.awaitModalSubmit({
                        filter: (interaction) => interaction.customId === id,
                        time: 60000
                    }).then(async (modalInteraction) => {
                        const newColor = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue("color-input").replaceAll("#", "");
                        const isValidHexColor = /^[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(newColor);
                        if (!isValidHexColor) {
                            await client.replyErrorHide(modalInteraction, `\`${newColor}\` не является правильным hex кодом цвета.`)
                            return;
                        }

                        await guild.updateOne({id: guildId}, {$set: {embed_color: newColor}}, {upsert: true});

                        colorEmbed.data.fields[0].value = `\`#${newColor}\``
                        colorEmbed.data.color = parseInt(newColor, 16)

                        await i.message.edit({embeds: [colorEmbed], components: [buttons]});
                        await client.replySuccessHide(modalInteraction, `Новый цвет сообщений успешно был установлен`)

                        if (newColor) {
                            buttons.components[2].data.disabled = false;
                            await i.message.edit({embeds: [colorEmbed], components: [buttons]});
                        } else {
                            buttons.components[2].data.disabled = true;
                            await i.message.edit({embeds: [colorEmbed], components: [buttons]});
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Произошла ошибка:", error);
                await i.reply({ content: "Error...", ephemeral: true });
            }
        })

        collector.on('end', async () => {
            console.log("Время коллектора истекло")
            collector.stop()
            await interaction.editReply({components: []});
        })
    }
}

module.exports = InteractionCreate;
```

I want to make settings, but when I click on any button I get the following errors:

```
Произошла ошибка: Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
    at ButtonInteraction.editReply (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:157:48)
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\src\events\client\interactions.js:97:29)
    at InteractionCollector.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at InteractionCollector.handleCollect (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:133:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'InteractionNotReplied'
}
Произошла ошибка: Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
    at ButtonInteraction.editReply (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:157:48)
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\src\events\client\interactions.js:97:29)
    at InteractionCollector.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at InteractionCollector.handleCollect (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:133:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'InteractionNotReplied'
}
09/20/2023 13:44:49 | [Main thread/ERROR] [ANTI-CRASH] Unhandled Rejection
DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at handleErrors (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.reply (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (D:\Кодинг\MatrixBot-git\src\events\client\interactions.js:157:17) {
  requestBody: { files: [], json: { type: 4, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1153959934510252042/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTE1Mzk1OTkzNDUxMDI1MjA0MjpnaVd5WndBSU12cG1xdHB6dVJySGQ2RlhuTW1rZmpvdmZid1BoYzFCRXNuUDc3VHBOS20zT2VXblltZUZEMXRxbnlLazNuUVcyTVVHSDN2VVdvSEhtblJPa2xDUnVwbHl5TEJYTjdheGJRUHpvajRialJueUNrR1RJVDNaSGJHVw/callback'
}
Время коллектора истекло
Время коллектора истекло
Время коллектора истекло
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the error message you get when you try to invoke the `editReply` function on an Interaction object, but, as the message indicates, you haven't actually made a reply to the Interaction yet.

Somewhere towards the top of your execute method, you need to either make an **initial** reply to the Interaction, using just the `interaction.reply()` method, or you can defer it using the `interaction.deferReply()` method. I personally prefer deferring the Interaction, because having to edit an existing message is more error prone.

```js
async execute(client, interaction) {
    await interaction.deferReply();
    // the rest of your code...
}
```

Also just FYI, you need to decide whether you want your replies to be ephemeral or not in the initial reply/defer. You can't make an ephemeral reply or deferral, and then call `editReply` and make it non-ephemeral.